# Executable stops working after saving from hex editor?

Tags: applications, binary

I've been playing around with binaries and clang. I was playing around and suddenly the executable stopped working for no apparent reason. Here's what I did:

1. Build hello world
   ex: `echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\n int main() { puts("Hello"); }' | clang -x c -`
2. Use `shasum` on `a.out`
3. Run `./a.out` to confirm it works
4. Open the binary in VS Code hex editor, change a letter, save
5. Run to confirm it not executing
6. Use `shasum` to confirm the sum is different
7. Change the letter back
8. Use `shasum` to confirm the sum is the original value
9. Run `./a.out` and see it still fail

Any idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here, changing `a.out` back to the original content in a hex editor makes it execute as expected. Are you sure you are executing the correct version in the second run?

Comment: @nohillside I'm 100% sure. What hex editor did you use? I'm on Venture using a M2.

Comment: @Stan How exactly does it fail? - It sounds likely you're seeing the effect of code signature validation caching or something similar.

Comment: I loaded it into Emacs and used hexl-mode.